# Launching DocList Webtop Component within a Container

Tags: documentum, emc, webtop

Are there any Documentum Webtop developers on here that know how to launch the **DocList** component within a simple container such as **dialogcontainer** ? I'm trying to implement some custom functionality for one of the screens in my Webtop-based application so that when the user clicks on the link for a folder, the DocList component is invoked to display the contents, then after the user is done looking at them, she can click the OK button provided by the container to return to the previous screen...

I've tried a couple different ways to do this. My first attempt was to use a *dmf:link* tag to call a new component I defined called **doclistcontainer** to contain the doclist component. My second attempt was to use a *dmf:actionlink* tag that called an action I defined which executes doclist within a container. In both cases, I end up with a blank screen, generic title, the OK button doesn't do anything... When I run a debugger on the code, I can see that the DocList behavioural class is being called despite the blank screen being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Sheldon

Comment: Can you provide code for both cases? which version are we talking about?

Comment: The version of Webtop is 6.7 SP2. I was actually using standard Webtop components, so I wasn't writing any code, just defining a new action and component in XML files. But I think I'm gonna try for a Capt. Kirk solution, i.e., I'm gonna change the parameters of the situation so that I no longer require a new component. The existing component allows for updates, i.e., it displays the results of a search using various parameters. So when my user clicks on a folder name in the results of a previous search, I'll pretend they want to search that folder and I'll update the results accordingly...